# Read XML File in Spark with multiple RowTags

Tags: apache-spark-sql, databricks, apache-spark-xml

I would like to read a huge XML File with 3 different RowTags into Apache Spark Dataframes.

RowTag = The XML Element, which you interpret as a row in Spark.

The Tags

- contain different data Structures
- are not overlapping

xml-spark (https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml) only offers to Read one RowTag a time, so I would need to read the same File 3 Times (not efficient).

Is there any way to read the file in one read ?

**Details:**

I have a huge XML File (24 GB) which contain 3 Lists:

```
<myFile>
    <ContainedResourceList>
        <SoundRecording><Title>A</Title></SoundRecording>
      ... several million records ...
        <SoundRecording><Title>Z</Title></SoundRecording>
    </ContainedResourceList>

    <ContainedReleaseList>
        <Release><ReleaseType>Single</ReleaseType></Release>
      ... several million records ...
        <Release><ReleaseType>LP</ReleaseType></Release>
    </ContainedReleaseList>

    <ContainedTransactionList>
        <Transaction><Sales>1</Sales></Transaction>
      ... several million records ...
        <Transaction><Sales>999</Sales></Transaction>
    </ContainedTransactionList>
</myFile>
```

The XML File is valid.
I want to read the RowTags SoundRecording, Release & Transaction.

I would prefer Scala libs, but I would be happy for any lib enabling the read.

**PS:**
How could the output & his schema look like ?

- Best Option: An Array of 3 DataFrames, one for each RowTag
- Ugly Option: One DataFrame containing the possible elements of all the 3 datastructures

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is to use the explode function. You can read the full xml with the rowTag set to ContainedResourceList and then with the resulting dataframe explode the dataframe with a new column

```
df.withColumn("soundRec", explode($"SoundRecording"))
```

You can add multiple columns for each tag you want to explode

Comment: I thank you for the suggested solution. The suggested "explode" solution works well for small files. But it fails on a huge File (24 GB) with: `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM Limit` 

In this solution, the whole ContainedResourceList is read into one record.
The ContainedResourceList contains ca. 10 million SoundRecordings. The ContainedResourceList size is ca. 1/3 of the input File.  
I tested on a 3 host Cluster each 8GB RAM. I could use more RAM, but using much RAM in order to read the file as a whole on one maschine was not the idea behind using Spark.

Answer (score 0):

From my usage of spark-xml, I understand it expects 2 tags in XML file,

1. root tag
2. row tag

and your input file should look something like below,

```
<root>
    <row>
        <FirstField> abc </FirstField>
        <SecondField> def <SecondField>
    </row>
    <row>
        <FirstField> ghi </FirstField>
        <SecondField> jkl <SecondField>
    </row>
    .
    .
    <row>
        <FirstField> uvw </FirstField>
        <SecondField> xyz <SecondField>
    </row>
</root>
```

and to read above file the syntax is

```
spark-shell --packages com.databricks:spark-xml_2.11:0.5.0
import com.databricks.spark.xml._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
val schema = StructType(List(StructField("FirstField",StringType,true),StructField("SecondField",StringType,true)))
val df = spark.read.option("rootTag","root").option("rowTag","row").schema(schema)xml("pathToFile")
```

in your case, you have a rootTag as "myFile" but there is now row tag. Thus you can try using "myFile"  as rowTag and the key point is you'll have to create your schema as follows,

```
val schema = StructType(List(StructField("ContainedResourceList",StringType,true),StructField("ContainedReleaseList",StringType,true),StructField("ContainedTransactionList",StringType,true)))
```

then read file,

```
 val df = spark.read.option("myFile","row").schema(schema).xml("pathToFile")
```

now you are good to process this df

you have repeated tags of SoundRecording, Release & Transaction, if you define schema for these then only 1st value among the repetition gets parse which is , `<Title>A</Title>, <ReleaseType>Single</ReleaseType>, <Sales>1</Sales>` in your case.

I am yet to figure out how to parse repeated tags in Spark-xml

Answer (score 0):

Reading myfile as row tag will result in one HUGE row and then exploding into rows will be done by one spark worker.

You can read them into 3 different dataframes specifying different rowtags, because each one has different schema. This would result in 3 different dataframe each with millions of rows, which would work more efficiently by spark.

To speedup processing you could pre split the xml file into multiple chunks and even by further into 3 sets of files ([Splitting XML file into multiple at given tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36155049/splitting-xml-file-into-multiple-at-given-tags)). This way multiple parts can be read in parallel by workers and when they finish with one part they can move to the next part. Otherwise only one worker will have to read the file sequentially and use it own way of partitioning and distribute them to the workers.

Then you can use spark-sql to join them together thats what you want to do.